# TypeError: this.contactService.verifyContact(...).subscribe is not a function

Tags: typescript

I've seen other questions about it, but none could help me.

```
    createEmergencyContactBoat(emergencyContactBoat: EmergencyContactBoat, number: string) {
        return this.db.connect().then(connection => {
            return this.contactService.verifyContact(number, connection).subscribe((result: any) => {
                if (!result){
                    throw new Error(ErrorMessage.CONTACT_DONT_EXIST);
                } 
                emergencyContactBoat.emergencyContact = result.id
                return connection.collection(this.collection).insertOne(emergencyContactBoat);
            })    
        })
    }
```

The class contact-service:

```
verifyContact(number: string, connection: any ) {
        return connection.collection(this.collection).findOne({emergencyContact: {$eq: true}, 
            contact: {$eq: number}}).then((result: any) => {
                return result
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to close a question with an answer instead of a comment:

The issue is due to the verifyContact method returns a Promise, and .subscribe method does not exists there. Subscribe method is used with RxJS Observable objects.

```
verifyContact(number: string, connection: any ) {
  return connection.collection(this.collection)
    .findOne({emergencyContact: {$eq: true}, contact: {$eq: number}})
    // You actually don't need this "then" block due to it just does nothing in this case.
    .then((result: any) => {
      return result;
    })
}
```

In order to fix an issue it was just needed to use `.then()` instead of `.subscribe()`

```
createEmergencyContactBoat(emergencyContactBoat: EmergencyContactBoat, number: string) {
  return this.db.connect().then(connection => {
    return this.contactService.verifyContact(number, connection).then((result: any) => {
      if (!result){
        throw new Error(ErrorMessage.CONTACT_DONT_EXIST);
      } 
      emergencyContactBoat.emergencyContact = result.id
      return connection.collection(this.collection).insertOne(emergencyContactBoat);
    })    
  })
}
```

Please get in the habit of explicitly specifying the return type of a function, this will save you from a significant number of errors and bugs in the future.